# Reducing generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to get an inheritance hierarchy of generics working, and I'm running into a bit of a problem.

Here's an example:

```
interface IFoo {}

interface IFoo<T> : IFoo 
{
    T Data { get; }
}

class Foo : IFoo<int> { public int Data { get; set; } }

interface IBar {}

class Bar : IBar { }

abstract class LayerOne<T_FOO, T_BAR> where T_FOO : IFoo where T_BAR : IBar {}
abstract class LayerTwo<T_FOO> : LayerOne<T_FOO, Bar> where T_FOO : IFoo, new()
{
    protected T_FOO _foo = new T_FOO();
    public void Test1() { _foo.Data.Dump();} // Compiler error
}

class LayerThree : LayerTwo<Foo> 
{
    public void Test2() { _foo.Data.Dump();}
}
```

I'm trying to get access to `.Data` in the `LayerTwo` class.  Clearly, since `IFoo` doesn't have that property, it's going to error.  However, if I change they type of `T_FOO` to `IFoo<T>`, then I have to define it and `LayerThree` as:

```
abstract class LayerTwo<T_FOO, T> : LayerOne<T_FOO, Bar> where T_FOO : IFoo<T>, new()
{
    protected T_FOO _foo = new T_FOO();
    public void Test1() { _foo.Data.Dump();}
}

class LayerThree : LayerTwo<Foo, int> 
{
    public void Test2() { _foo.Data.Dump();}
}
```

But the intent of the concrete `Foo` implementation is that it *already knows* it's implementing `IFoo<int>`.  **Is there any way I can get `LayerTwo` to know about the `Data` property without requiring it to be looked up from `Foo` and added to `LayerThree`'s definition?**

What I'd love is:

```
class LayerThree : LayerTwo<Foo> // Automatically realizes that the second generic is int
{
    public void Test2() { _foo.Data.Dump();}
}
```

---

**Update:** As it turns out, I was actually trying to implement two contradictory things in my code. The actual `LayerTwo` was trying to keep `T_FOO` generic, but also created an (abstract) method which required a specific type from `IFoo<T>`.
So the solution I'm going with is just to use an interface which inherits from `IFoo<T>` and specifies the type, but I'm accepting Ondrej Tucny's answer, since it *did* solve the problem I asked about.

Comment: too many `Foo` and `Bar`, my brain asploded! At least use `TFoo` and `TBar` for the generic params :)

Comment: Also, ive run into this problem so many times I've named it "Generic pass-the-parcel". Thats copyright me, but you can use it!

Comment: @Jamiec - Good point. I was going to do that, then forgot in the midst of rewriting it.

Comment: I'd say unlikely: `Foo : IFoo<int>, IFoo<string>, IFoo<double>` is perfectly valid class (strange, so what?) - as result `Data` may be property of any of 3 interfaces (and in addition private on `Foo` itself).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - True, but at that point you have to implement them explicitly anyway.  Even with the middle code (the one that compiles but I want to avoid), you can't access a non-explicit `Data`.

Comment: But code that compile does indeed cast to interface before the call (I'm not sure if there is explicit cast or something else but compiler knows to call `IFoo<T>.Data` - because it knows nothing else about `Foo` itself). So you want compiler magically pick the right of several possible interfaces...

Comment: This is why I always think three times before adding generics into my designs.

Comment: @Euphoric - One generic is pretty painless.  Multiple starts hurting.

Comment: @Bobson Even one can become pain in the ass when it spreads over half of your architecture.

Comment: @Euphoric - True.  It's *easier* to contain, but that doesn't mean it can't get out of control.  That's kindof what's happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the same situation as with `IEnumerable` / `IEnumerable<T>`. Your weakly typed interface `IFoo` needs to provide a weakly typed `Data`:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    object Data { get; }
}

public interface IFoo<T> : IFoo
{
    new T Data { get; }
}
```

then in the implementation one of the will be explicit to favor strongly typed access:

```
public class IntFoo : IFoo<int>
{
    public int Data { get { return -1; } }

    object IFoo.Data { get { return Data; } }
}
```

Now you have access to `Data` in either case, although when the actual type `T` is unknown, you have to live with an `object`.

Comment: Ooh, that looks promising.  I'll go give it a shot.

Comment: +0: @Bobson - while it is good idea I think it is unlikely to help you - you'll get `object IFoo.Data` in your `LayerTwo`/`LayerThree` and will not be able to call methods of it...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Between `var`, extension methods, and other functions on `IFoo`, I think I can work around that.

Comment: Thanks, Ondrej!  In implementing this, I found out why I kept going in circles with my code (see the update to my question), so I didn't end up *actually* needing this after all, but I'm definitely keeping it implemented.

Comment: @Bobson Great to hear that! It's frequently a good idea to provide both strongly a weakly typed access to data in such situations. However, I'd always favor strongly typed over weakly typed, and so keep the implementations of weakly typed stuff explicit to enforce an explicit cast.